# DevExpress get stylesheet add variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, devextreme

I am working in an ASP.net MVC app using javascript.  I am using a devExpress dxSwitch to try to change the theme of the page.

I have this code in my head of my _layout.cshtml

```
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets( "dark",
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Dashboard}
)
```

Instead of hard coding "dark" in for the theme I want to see if I could use a variable in place of it and  apply this function to switch between light and dark.

```
$('#switch').click(function () {


            var whichTheme = $("#switch").dxSwitch("instance");
            var valueSwitch = whichTheme.option("value");
            if (valueSwitch === true) {

                $('body').css('background-color', '#343434');

            } else {

                $('body').css('background-color', 'whitesmoke');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no chance to do it this way. Javascript and Razor dosen't communicate, because the rendering happens before jQuery starts to work.

I would look at the outcoming HTML from DevExpress and only then add or change styles in the element itself or in a style tag on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is something like this https://codecentral.devexpress.com/E3825/Home/PostTheme, you can do this but  it is not as simple as you think, please check this sample code

```
namespace MvcApp_Theme {
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start() {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            DevExpressHelper.Theme = Utils.CurrentTheme;
        }
    }
}
```

You have the entire code here in this link https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3825/how-to-change-a-theme-on-the-fly